# how to solve org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException

Tags: solr, solrj

I got the following error:

[image: Following error is appear]

This is my code:

[image: Please format this as code]

Comment: What does the server log say? The reason for an HTML response is usually that something went wrong on the server side (404, 503, etc.) Also, please post stack traces as text and not as an image.

Comment: You are missing solr collection name

Comment: Please do not use screenshots of code. Instead, [edit] to copy-paste your code in the question, then select it and press CTRL+K or the `{}` button to format it.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, I see one problem: You never tell the `SolrServer` which core or collection to address. As is stated in the [SolrJ docs](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_2_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrClient.html):

```
There are two ways to use an HttpSolrClient:

  1) Pass a URL to the constructor that points directly at a particular core
  SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient("http://my-solr-server:8983/solr/core1");

In this case, you can query the given core directly, but you cannot query any other cores or issue CoreAdmin requests with this client.

  2) Pass the base URL of the node to the constructor

  SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient("http://my-solr-server:8983/solr");
  QueryResponse resp = client.query("core1", new SolrQuery("*:*"));
```

BTW: You should use that `Solrclient` object that you commented out. The `SolrServer` objects are deprecated.